# Is it okay to have 1000 rows in a single partition?

Tags: cassandra

I have multi tenancy model

```
tenant_template (
    tenant_id int,
    sub_org_id int, 
    code text, 
    active bool,
    ......
)
```

with partition key -> `(tenant_id, sub_org_id)`
and clustering key -> `code`

we have to fetch all active configs with for admin api ,

maximum active row may be till 1000 ( single row size would be around 11 KB).

1. is it good fetch all data from db ?
2. any best practice for number of rows should be single partition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, 1000 rows is fine and is quite small compared to a lot of data models.

Cassandra can have a maximum of 2 billion cells (or 2<sup>31</sup> which is the size of a Java integer) in a single partition. If your table had 10 columns, that's a total of 10K cells (`1000 rows x 10 columns`) which is well below the limit.

Assuming you calculated the row size correctly, the partition size would also be well below the recommended 100MB/partition (not a hard limit, just a recommendation).

One important thing to note is that what is good for one cluster may not necessarily be good for another. There are a lot of factors that go into assessing whether the conditions you outlined are acceptable. These include (but not limited to) use case, access patterns, hardware (CPU, memory, disks), cluster load, and so on.

We always recommend that you test thoroughly with production-like loads and data to determine whether your data model is suitable for your use case. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

The rules of thumb for partitioning in Cassandra are:

- Less than 100.000 items per partition
- Partition size less than 100MB
- Row less than 10MB

But it is not arbitrary or anything like this and performance testing is always welcomed before going into production. Big partitions are not easy to move and compact.

I think what you described is good.

Comment: Less than 100.000 items per partition.   you are saying 100 ?

Comment: No, that wasn't meant to be 100.
Because row sizes will vary, this is meant to be the number of cells.
The max partition limit is 2 billion cells, but the rule of thumb is when you hit a cell count higher than 100k, consider if the data model is optimal, you can reference this page:
https://docs.datastax.com/en/dseplanning/docs/data-model.html#number-of-cells-per-partition